# search one or more keywords in multiple table fields

Tags: ms-access, vbscript, asp-classic

I have below a search script to perform a keyword search in one table column.

Search page:

```
<form name="form_6" method="get" action="results_keywords.asp">
<input name="keyword" type="text" placeholder="keyword" size="30">
<input id="submit" type="submit" value="search">
</form>
```

part of Results page:

```
<%
Dim rsKeyword__MMColParam
rsKeyword__MMColParam = "1"
If (Request.QueryString("keyword") <> "") Then 
  rsKeyword__MMColParam = Request.QueryString("keyword")
End If
%>
<%
Dim rsKeyword
Dim rsKeyword_numRows

Set rsKeyword = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
rsKeyword.ActiveConnection = MM_cnKeywords_STRING
rsKeyword.Source = "SELECT * FROM reports WHERE keyword = '" + Replace(rsKeyword__MMColParam, "'", "''") + "' ORDER BY number DESC"
.....
```

This works fine.
Now I like to perform the same GET search field to search in 10 different table columns (keyword01, keyword02, etc.).

Perfect would be if the GET search field could contain multiple keywords which will be searched for in the mentioned 10 different table columns.
Is this possible? Any help/suggestion is much appreciated.

Switching from Access Table to a SQL database is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear whether you want to search for a single keyword in multiple columns, or all keywords in all columns, or what. I went with the simplest option below, i.e. 10 input fields, where the keyword entered in the first one goes with the first keyword column, the second field goes with the second column, etc. I also wasn't sure whether this was to be an `AND` search or an `OR` search; I guessed the latter. (You could add a field to the form for the user to select AND or OR.)

This could get too unwieldy for using the querystring. If that happens, just change the method to "post" and use `Request.Form()` instead of `Request.Querystring()`.

```
<form method="get" action="mypage.asp">
<p>Enter keyword(s) to search for:
<%
For i = 1 to 10
    Response.Write "<br>Field " & i & ": <input type='text' name='kw" & i & "' size='15'>"
Next
%>
</p>
<p><input type="submit" value="Search"></p>
</form>

<%
dim i, kw(10), rs, sql

For i = 1 to 10
    kw(i) = Request.Querystring("kw" & i)
    kw(i) = Replace(kw(i),"'","''") '- double up apostrophes
    '- if this is a form for internal use only, you can stop here.
    '- Otherwise, try to clean things up a bit.
    kw(i) = Replace(Replace(kw(i),",",""),";","") '- remove commas and semicolons
    '- etc. - do whatever you can to ensure the inputs are keywords, not sql statements
Next

sql = "SELECT * FROM reports WHERE "
For i = 1 to 10
    If kw(i) <> "" Then
        sql = sql & "(keyword" & Right(100+i,2) & " = '" & kw(i) & "') OR "
        '- that "Right(...)" business is so that you get keyword01, not keyword1
    End If
Next
sql = Left(sql,Len(sql)-4) '- remove last "OR"
sql = sql & " ORDER BY number"
rs = Server.Createobject("ADODB.Recordset")
rs.ActiveConnection = MM_cnKeywords_STRING
rs.Source = sql
...
%>
```

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps.

```
rsKeyword__MMColParam = "1"
If (Request.QueryString("keyword") <> "") Then

'Assuming keywords entered in the search field are separated by a comma.
'Place keywords in an array
CDArray = Split(Request.QueryString("keyword") , ",")

'Get the number of keywords entered to use for the loops
jMax = ubound(CDArray)
End If

'create a variable to store the search criteria
Dim mysearch

'Use a real field name, e.g, the record id field to use
'as a beginning dummy search criteria. 
'Makes the following loops easier to add/manage.
mysearch = " (afieldname <> '')"


'Loop through the array for each field you want to search.
'In this case, 10 fields.
'Adding the results to the variable.

for j = 0 to jMax
mysearch = mysearch & " OR (fieldname1 LIKE '%" & CDArray(j) & "%')"
next

for j = 0 to jMax
mysearch = mysearch & " OR (fieldname2 LIKE '%" & CDArray(j) & "%')"
next

for j = 0 to jMax
mysearch = mysearch & " OR (fieldname3 LIKE '%" & CDArray(j) & "%')"
next

for j = 0 to jMax
mysearch = mysearch & " OR (fieldname4 LIKE '%" & CDArray(j) & "%')"
next

for j = 0 to jMax
mysearch = mysearch & " OR (fieldname5 LIKE '%" & CDArray(j) & "%')"
next

for j = 0 to jMax
mysearch = mysearch & " OR (fieldname6 LIKE '%" & CDArray(j) & "%')"
next

for j = 0 to jMax
mysearch = mysearch & " OR (fieldname7 LIKE '%" & CDArray(j) & "%')"
next

for j = 0 to jMax
mysearch = mysearch & " OR (fieldname8 LIKE '%" & CDArray(j) & "%')"
next

for j = 0 to jMax
mysearch = mysearch & " OR (fieldname9 LIKE '%" & CDArray(j) & "%')"
next

for j = 0 to jMax
mysearch = mysearch & " OR (fieldname10 LIKE '%" & CDArray(j) & "%')"
next

'Now add the completed search variable to the select string
rsKeyword.Source = "SELECT * FROM reports WHERE" & mysearch & " ORDER BY number DESC"
```

Answer (score 0):

@Martha
My idea is to perform a (multiple) keyword search using ONE input field using 10 table columns containing max. 10 keywords/report.

@Craig
Using this code results in a Internal Server Error. Where is my mistake?

```
<%
Dim rsKeyword__MMColParam
rsKeyword__MMColParam = "1"
If (Request.QueryString("Keyword") <> "") Then 
CDArray = Split(Request.QueryString("Keyword") , ",")
jMax = ubound(CDArray)
End If
%>
<%
Dim rsKeyword
Dim rsKeyword_numRows
Dim mysearch

mysearch = " (Keyword01 <> '')"

for j = 0 to jMax
mysearch = mysearch & " OR (Keyword01 LIKE '%" & CDArray(j) & "%')"
next

for j = 0 to jMax
mysearch = mysearch & " OR (Keyword02 LIKE '%" & CDArray(j) & "%')"
next

for j = 0 to jMax
mysearch = mysearch & " OR (Keyword03 LIKE '%" & CDArray(j) & "%')"
next

for j = 0 to jMax
mysearch = mysearch & " OR (Keyword04 LIKE '%" & CDArray(j) & "%')"
next

for j = 0 to jMax
mysearch = mysearch & " OR (Keyword05 LIKE '%" & CDArray(j) & "%')"
next

for j = 0 to jMax
mysearch = mysearch & " OR (Keyword06 LIKE '%" & CDArray(j) & "%')"
next

for j = 0 to jMax
mysearch = mysearch & " OR (fieldname07 LIKE '%" & CDArray(j) & "%')"
next

for j = 0 to jMax
mysearch = mysearch & " OR (Keyword08 LIKE '%" & CDArray(j) & "%')"
next

for j = 0 to jMax
mysearch = mysearch & " OR (Keyword09 LIKE '%" & CDArray(j) & "%')"
next

for j = 0 to jMax
mysearch = mysearch & " OR (Keyword10 LIKE '%" & CDArray(j) & "%')"
next

Set rsKeyword = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
rsKeyword.ActiveConnection = MM_cnKeyword_STRING

rsKeyword.Source = "SELECT * FROM reports WHERE " & mysearch & " ORDER BY number DESC" 
rsKeyword.CursorType = 0
rsKeyword.CursorLocation = 2
rsKeyword.LockType = 1
rsKeyword.Open()

rsKeyword_numRows = 0
%>
```